# Nexus and OpenLDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, nexus, openldap

I´m trying to configure my Nexus instance, 2.11, to integrate with LDAP, OpenLDAP, with SSL.

It appears to work with the settings bellow:

> **Connection**
>  Protocol: ldaps
>  Hostname: mydomain.local
>  Port: 636
>  Search Base: dc=mydomain,dc=local
>  
>   **Authentication**
>  Auth. Method: Simple Authentication
>  SASL Realm: 
>  Username: dc=admi,dc=mydomain,dc=local
>   Password: MySuperSecretPassword

When I click on **Check Authentication** it returns:

---

> LDAP connection and authentication test completed Successfully.

---

Then in sections:

> **User element Mapping**
>  Base DN: ou=users
>  User subtree:  (but it doesn´t appear to affect something)
>  Object
>   class: inetOrgPerson
>  User filter: 
>  User UD Attribute:
>   uid
>  Real Name Attribute: cn
>  E-Mail Attribute: mail
>   Password Attribute: 
>  
>  Group Element Mapping

Then clicking on **Check User Mapping**, it return all the users on LDAP directory.

It´s good, but... When I´m trying to Log-In with any user, it returns:

---

> Incorrect username, password or no permission to use Nexus User
>   Interface. Try again. Please login before attempting further requests.

---

I´d try to mapp a user from LDAP, in User Manegement interface, and give this user a Nexus Administrator Rule, I tried to put all roles to this user, but always get the same error above.

Is there any other configuration nedded to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Go under "administration/server" and make sure the LDAP security realm has been added to the list of configured security realms.

Comment: That was It... @rseddon, thaks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

In the administration sidebar, click 'server'

[image]

Enable "OSS LDAP Authentication Realm" in the security realm.

[image]

There is a feature request to make this more visible.

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-4062